# Nested Json parsing using Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have tried to parse this JSON using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) but I couldn’t.
Can anyone help me to parse this JSON using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

**JSON:**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "results": {
        "favourites": [
            {
                "id": "UB3172",
                "name": "Masdar Headquarters"
            },
            {
                "id": "UB1438",
                "name": "Guggenheim Abu Dhabi on Saadiyat Island"
            },
            {
                "id": "UB4838",
                "name": "Watani Residential Development in Abu Dhabi - 600 Villas and 48 Buildings"
            },
            {
                "id": "UB4795",
                "name": "Two Mosques in Mohammed Bin Zayed City"
            },
            {
                "id": "UB1274",
                "name": "2 Workers Residential City at Al Ain Industrial City"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried this one for JSON parser class:

```
public class ProjectList {
    public String status;
    public String results;

    public class Favourites{
    public  String id;
    public  String name;
    }

}
```

In MainActivit

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(result);
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        List<ProjectList.Favourites> fav=new ArrayList<ProjectList.Favourites>();
        fav=Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, ProjectList.Favourites.class));
```

Comment: Did you try anything.

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `POJO` class as follows

```
class MyResponse {
        public String status;

        public Result results;

        public static class Favourites {

            public String id;
            public String name;
        }

        public static class Result {

            public List<Favourites> favourites;
        }

    }
```

and pass it to gson as

```
MyResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(yourResponse, MyResponse.class);
```

idea is that maintain the hierarchy of key-value pairs with appropriate POJO's

Comment: I think classes should be `public` and don't forget to edit the proguard obfucator (if involved) ... :)

Comment: How did i retrieve those id and name using this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your pojos here : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Sometimes gson cannot convert your objects from json. In this case you have to write your own deserializer and use it with gson builder.

Edit: If you use proguard before release your project (if you set proguard to change your pojos variable names) gson cannot match class variable names, json names so it cannot convert your objects. You have to add @SerializedName("your_variable_name") annotaion.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String jsonRespone = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"results\":{\"favourites\":[{\"id\":\"UB3172\",\"name\":\"Masdar Headquarters\"},{\"id\":\"UB1438\",\"name\":\"Guggenheim Abu Dhabi on Saadiyat Island\"},{\"id\":\"UB4838\",\"name\":\"Watani Residential Development in Abu Dhabi - 600 Villas and 48 Buildings\"},{\"id\":\"UB4795\",\"name\":\"Two Mosques in Mohammed Bin Zayed City\"},{\"id\":\"UB1274\",\"name\":\"2 Workers Residential City at Al Ain Industrial City\"}]}}";

String status;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> favouritesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try{
   JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(jsonRespone);
   status = responseJson.getString("status");

   JSONArray favouriteJsonArray = responseJson.getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("favourites");

   for (int i=0;i<favouriteJsonArray.length();i++){
       HashMap<String,String> favourite = new HashMap<String, String>();
       favourite.put("id",favouriteJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
       favourite.put("name",favouriteJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
       favouritesList.add(favourite);
   }

   System.out.print("status : "+status);
   for (HashMap<String, String> favourite : favouritesList) {
        System.out.print("id : "+favourite.get("id"));
        System.out.print("name : "+favourite.get("name"));
   }
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```